# Python re infinite execution

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to execute this code :

```
import re
pattern = r"(\w+)\*([\w\s]+)*/$"
re_compiled = re.compile(pattern)
results = re_compiled.search('COPRO*HORIZON 2000                 HOR')
print(results.groups())
```

But Python does not respond. The process takes 100% of the CPU and does not stop. I've tried this both on Python 2.7.1 and Python 3.2 with identical results.

Comment: I had the same problem - waited **more than 2 minutes** to a substitution to end. Finally, installed the package `regex` - worked great - the substitution was finished immediately. You can install from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your regex runs into [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) because you have nested quantifiers (`([...]+)*`). Since your regex requires the string to end in `/` (which fails on your example), the regex engine tries all permutations of the string in the vain hope to find a matching combination. That's where it gets stuck.

To illustrate, let's assume `"A*BCD"` as the input to your regex and see what happens:

1. `(\w+)` matches `A`. Good.
2. `\*` matches `*`. Yay.
3. `[\w\s]+` matches `BCD`. OK.
4. `/` fails to match (no characters left to match). OK, let's back up one character.
5. `/` fails to match `D`. Hum. Let's back up some more.
6. `[\w\s]+` matches `BC`, and the repeated `[\w\s]+` matches `D`.
7. `/` fails to match. Back up.
8. `/` fails to match `D`. Back up some more.
9. `[\w\s]+` matches `B`, and the repeated `[\w\s]+` matches `CD`.
10. `/` fails to match. Back up again.
11. `/` fails to match `D`. Back up some more, again.
12. How about `[\w\s]+` matches `B`, repeated `[\w\s]+` matches `C`, repeated `[\w\s]+` matches `D`? No? Let's try something else.
13. `[\w\s]+` matches `BC`. Let's stop here and see what happens.
14. Darn, `/` still doesn't match `D`.
15. `[\w\s]+` matches `B`.
16. Still no luck. `/` doesn't match `C`.
17. Hey, the whole group is optional `(...)*`.
18. Nope, `/` still doesn't match `B`.
19. OK, I give up.

Now that was a string of just three letters. Yours had about 30, trying all permutations of which would keep your computer busy until the end of days.

I suppose what you're trying to do is to get the strings before/after `*`, in which case, use

```
pattern = r"(\w+)\*([\w\s]+)$"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [re2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/re2/) or any other regular expression engine base on automata theory. The one in a current python re module is a simple and slow backtracking engine (for now, things may change in future). But automata based engines have some restriction, it wouldn't allow you to use backreferences for example. Collate with this [re2 syntax page](http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax) to find out will it satisfy your needs or not.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, Perl runs it very quickly

```
-> perl -e 'print "Match\n" if "COPRO*HORIZON 2000                 HOR" =~ m|(\w+)\*([\w\s]+)*/$|'
-> perl -e 'print "Match\n" if "COPRO*HORIZON 2000                 HOR/" =~ m|(\w+)\*([\w\s]+)*/$|'
Match
```

Comment: Yes, Perl contains many optimizations that have the effect of compensating for mistakes commonly made by regex authors.

Comment: Furthermore, Perl stops executing the regexp when the number of backtracks exceed some predefined value.

Comment: @ovgolovin that's almost completely untrue. There's a recursion-depth limit in the regex engine that applies in some exceptionally cases, but there is no limit on backtracking in general. And Perl wouldn't just (possibly wrongly) report a failed match in such a case; it prints an error.

Comment: @AlanMoore in this case it's an optimization that's profitable even for many well-written regexes; a fixed string that appears in the regex has to appear in the candidate string as well, or else the string can't possibly match. Anchored fixed strings are *very* cheap to check for; it's basically just a `strncmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be something in your pattern.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the last '*' in your expression.  The following code seems to work for me:

```
import re

pattern = r"(\w+)\*([\w\s]+)$"

re_compiled = re.compile(pattern)

results = re_compiled.search('COPRO*HORIZON 2000                 HOR')

print(results.groups())
```